# .htaccess allow social media crawlers to work (Facebook and Twitter) | Angular 11 SPA

Tags: angular, facebook, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, meta-tags

I've created a SPA - Single Page Application with Angular 11 which I'm hosting on a shared hosting server.

The issue I have with it is that I cannot share any of the pages I have (except the first route - /) on social media (Facebook and Twitter) because the meta tags aren't updating (I have a Service which is handling the meta tags for each page) based on the requested page (I know this is because Facebook and Twitter aren't crawling JavaScript).

In order to fix this issue I tried Angular Universal (SSR - Server Side Rendering) and Scully (creates static pages). Both (Angular Universal and Scully) are fixing my issue but I would prefer using the default Angular SPA build.

The approach I am taking:

- Files structure (shared hosting server /public_html/):

```
- crawlers/
           - crawlers.php
           - share/
                   - 404.json
                   - about.json
                   - work.json
- .htaccess
- index.html
```

- crawlers.php contains the following:

```
<?php

$page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page');

if (file_exists('./share/'.$page.'.json')) {
    $file = file_get_contents('./share/'.$page.'.json');
} else {
    $file = file_get_contents('./share/404.json');
}

$data = json_decode($file);

return makePage($data); 

function makePage($data) { 
    $html  = '<!doctype html>'.PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '<html>'.PHP_EOL;

    $html .= '<head>'.PHP_EOL;

    $html .= '<meta property="og:type" content="website" />'.PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Website" />'.PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '<meta property="og:title" content="'.$data->title.'" />'.PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '<meta property="og:description" content="'.$data->description.'" />'.PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$data->image.'" />'.PHP_EOL;

    $html .= '<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>'.PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '<meta name="twitter:title" content="'.$data->title.'" />'.PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '<meta name="twitter:description" content="'.$data->description.'" />'.PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '<meta name="twitter:image" content="'.$data->image.'" />'.PHP_EOL;
    
    $html .= '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$data->url.'">'.PHP_EOL;

    $html .= '</head>'.PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '<body></body>'.PHP_EOL;

    $html .= '</html>';

    echo $html;
}

?>
```

`og:url` is not specified because I thought that by not specifying it, Facebook will be unaware of the actual content URL and will link its cards to the static file. It shouldn't be a problem as I made use of the `http-equiv="refresh"`, which will redirect normal users to the correct URL.

- For example, 404.json contains the following:

```
{
  "title": "404: Not Found | My Website",
  "description": "My awesome description.",
  "image": "https://www.mywebsite.com/assets/images/share/404.jpg",
  "url": "https://www.mywebsite.com",
}
```

- .htaccess contains the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Allow robots.txt to pass through
RewriteRule ^robots.txt - [L]

# Allow social media crawlers to work
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /crawlers/crawlers.php?page=$1 [NC,L]

# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

When I am testing crawlers/crawlers.php?page=test-page, it works perfectly (after accessing `https://www.mywebsite.com/crawlers/crawlers.php?page=test-page`), reason why I believe the issue is in the .htaccess condition below `# Allow social media crawlers to work`. Sharing on Facebook still shows the meta tags of the first route (/), which means that the redirect to crawlers/crawlers.php doesn't work.

Also, on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/ the url `https://www.mywebsite.com/about` is not redirecting to `https://www.mywebsite.com/crawelers/crawlers.php?page=about`.

I want to use the redirect to crawlers/crawlers.php for social media crawlers only for pages like this: `https://www.mywebsite.com/about`, `https://www.mywebsite.com/work`, etc but not for `https://www.mywebsite.com` (the first route - /).

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to handle this via an _external_ redirect in the first place?

Comment: @CBroe I don't know any other way to handle this issue without using Angular Universal (or Scully, Prerender.io, etc).

Comment: But what does that have to do, with external vs internal redirect? Your `crawlers.php` script “lives” within the same domain setup on the web server, does it not? An external redirect would be problematic, because Facebook would take that to mean, that _this_ is the URL you actually want to share. And if you set the original URL as `og:url` value, then Facebook will request _that_ again, so you will end up in a redirect loop.

Comment: @CBroe I didn't understand what changes you suggest. I changed in ```.htaccess``` ```RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/crawlers/crawlers.php?page=$1 [R=301,L]``` to ```RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /crawlers/crawlers.php?page=$1 [NC,L]```. Also, I removed the ```og:url``` and ```canonical``` from ```crawlers.php```. I thought that by doing so Facebook will be unaware of the actual content URL and will link its cards to the static file. It shouldn't be a problem as I made use of the ```http-equiv="refresh"```, which will redirect normal users to the correct URL. However, it doesn't work...

Comment: I’m guessing the rewrite itself isn’t working in the first place? When you configure rewriting in .htaccess, the path RewriteRule matches against _never_ starts with a leading slash, that has been stripped off at this point already.

Comment: @CBroe I also believe the RewriteCond or the RewriteRule is the actual issue. I want to use the redirect to ```crawlers.php``` for social media crawlers (Facebook and Twitter) only for pages like this: ```https://www.mywebsite.com/about```, ```https://www.mywebsite.com/work```, etc but not for ```https://www.mywebsite.com``` (the first route - /), reason why I used the leading slash.

Comment: The leading slash has been stripped off at this point already, so you want to differentiate between a _completely empty_ (relative) path here, and one that contains … “something”. Try `^(.+)$` instead.

Comment: @CBroe I tried ```^(.+)$``` and it doesn't fix the issue...

Comment: Comment out the RewriteCond, then you can easily test in your browser, whether the redirect itself works, regardless of the user agent. If yes, then the condition is wrong; if no, then the RewriteRule itself is. (And you might have to add something that prevents the rewrite from happening again for `crawlers.php`, so that you don’t create an endless loop there.)

Comment: @CBroe By commenting out the RewriteCond, the browser (and Facebook) receives the new blank page with the correct meta tags from ```crawlers.php```. Indeed, the issue is in the RewriteCond.

Comment: @CBroe However, the og:image wasn't loaded so I moved the lines from```# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is``` above ```# Allow social media crawlers to work``` but Sharing Debugger still tells me that ```Provided og:image URL, https://www.mywebsite.com/assets/images/share/404.jpg could not be processed as an image because it has an invalid content type.``` which is weird as the first route has the same content type.

Comment: What Content-Type header _does_ your server respond with for that URL?

Comment: @CBroe For that URL, the Content-Type header is ```image/jpeg```. The first route (/), which works fine has the same Content-Type header. The only difference is that the first route (/) doesn't use the ```RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /crawlers/crawlers.php?page=$1 [NC,L]```.

Comment: _“For that URL, the Content-Type header is image/jpeg”_ - should be, or _is_ (when requested by the FB scraper, with whatever rewriting based on the UA you have in place now)?

Comment: _“because it has an invalid content type”_ could also be due to the fact, that some _error_ occurred (probably due to the rewriting, like an endless redirect that hits the internal redirect limit), so the web server returns the error document specified for the specific error code, and that’s likely to be `text/html`, rather than an actual image.

Comment: @CBroe I added that URL in Postman in order to view its Content-Type header. In the Sharing Debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/), after clicking on *See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL*, besides the meta tags I added (which looks fine), there is a ```<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">``` but I don't think this is causing the problem since it is referring to the new blank page. If I take the URL of that image and paste it in the browser, I get the image as a response (as expected).

Comment: Try and re-scrape the image URL itself using the debug tool, it might just be that Facebook still has older data cached for that one.

Comment: @CBroe I fixed the issue with the image by renaming it. It was doing this issue only for ```404.jpg``` and after changing the name to ```not-found.jpg``` it works fine. The only issue left is to add the correct ```RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}```. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Can’t currently see what’s wrong with that. I’d get a browser extension that allows you to manipulate the User Agent, that’ll make for some easier testing in this situation. If that doesn’t help, then try and log  somewhere, what UA the FB scraper actually sends, maybe it is a different value than expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CBroe's guidance, I managed to make the social media (Facebook and Twitter) crawlers work (without using Angular Universal, Scully, Prerender.io, etc) for an Angular 11 SPA - Single Page Application, which I'm hosting on a shared hosting server.

The issue I had in the question above was in `.htaccess`.

This is my `.htaccess` (which works as expected):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Force www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Allow robots.txt to pass through
RewriteRule ^robots.txt - [L]

# Allow social media crawlers to work
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit|WhatsApp|LinkedInBot|Twitterbot)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /crawlers/social_media.php?page=$1 [R=301,L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

*PS I renamed `crawlers.php` to `social_media.php`, added WhatsApp and LinkedIn user agents and also added a redirect from mywebsite.com to [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com)*